# JSON decoding not working with Python Requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I cannot decode my request's reponse into a useful format. Here's the code:

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.tsx.com/json/company-directory/search/tsx/%5EC?callback=jQuery17109078120971266259_1565471114746&_=1565481666704"

r = requests.get(url)
```

I tried tinkering with these variations from ideas on the forums, but I get the following error message:

File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

```
r = requests.get(url).json()
```

Or

```
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
```

with no success...
To show what I am trying to decode: here are the first lines output of r.text:

```
In [71]: runfile('C:/python...)
b'jQuery17109078120971266259_1565471114739({"last_updated":1565340914,"length":158,"results":[{"symbol":"AUMB","name":"1911 Gold Corporation","instruments":[{"symbol":"AUMB","name":"1911 Gold Corporation"}]},{"symbol":"ALBS.P","name":"A-Labs Capital I Corp.","instruments":[{"symbol":"ALBS.P","name":"A-Labs Capital I Corp."}]},{"symbol":"ALAB.P","name":"A-Labs Capital II Corp.","instruments":[{"symbol":"ALAB.P","name":"A-Labs Capital II Corp."}]},...
```

Side note: I found the "AJAX" URL under "network" in the Google Chrome developer tools. These efforts are the result of me not being able to scrape a website using traditional BS4 and learning about requests ability to scrape AJAX content, if I can use the term AJAX content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is because the request text is not actually a valid `json` format. It has some extra text which are the jquery call from the frontend.

With a little bit of `regex` you are able to actually extract the `json` from the results you just presented, and use as a `json` object in `python`:

- `(?:jQuery[0-9_]*\()(.+)(?:\);)`, which in essence means:
- `(?:jQuery[0-9_]*\()` Starts with jQuery, has a big number with possible underscores (non-capturing);
- `(.+)` Anything in between
- `(?:\);)` Ends with a bracket and semi-colon (non-capturing)

Here the results:

```py
import json
import re

r = requests.get(url)
results = json.loads(re.findall('(?:jQuery[0-9_]*\()(.+)(?:\);)', r.text)[0])

results
Out[1]:
{'last_updated': 1565340925,
 'length': 197,
 'results': [{'symbol': 'CLIQ',
   'name': 'Alcanna Inc.',
   'instruments': [{'symbol': 'CLIQ', 'name': 'Alcanna Inc.'},
    {'symbol': 'CLIQ.DB', 'name': 'Alcanna Inc 31JA22Db'}]},
...
```

Comment: It works, no editing needed. Great response, huge thanks!